# A point is selected uniformly at random in the interior of a unit square...

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

[image]From It, the altitude to each side of the square is drawn. For each side, a stick of the altitude's length is obtained. Determine the probability that you can select three of the sticks and arrange them to form a triangle.

Some of the problems I have with this problem are, don't know how to draw the diagram, not understanding the problem.
How could I arrange those sticks. And how to draw the altitudes?

Does the probability vary on the length of squares sides

Comment: Begin by drawing a square, say with opposite corners at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Make a pencil mark inside the square. Then draw lines from the point to the four sides, with each line intersecting its side of the square perpendicularly.  Then edit your question to ask more help.

Comment: Draw a square, take a point $P$ inside the square. Draw the two lines through $P$ parallel to the sides until they meet the sides. So you are making a "cross." The altitudes are the $4$ lengths.

Comment: Consider the condition that makes the three lengths the sides of a triangle. The answer will then be immediate.

Comment: But there ll be more probabilities if you extend the sides of the square? Right?

Comment: The probability is independent of the side of the square: it is $1$ for all squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality we may assume that the square is a $2\times 2$. 
Two what? Two half-units.

Then the four lengths of the altitudes can be taken to be $1+s$, $1-s$, $1+t$, and $1-t$, where $0\le s\le t\lt 1$.

We claim that the lengths $1+t$, $1+s$, $1-s$ are the sides of a triangle.

Since $1+t\ge 1+s\ge 1-s$, it is enough to verify that the sum of the two smaller sides $1+s$ and $1-s$ is greater than the larger side. But this sum is $2$, which is $\gt 1+t$.

The required probability is therefore $1$.

Comment: What do mean by the half units? Why those

Comment: Also could you attached a diagram

Comment: Labeled with s and t, please

Comment: The units thing was a joke. The problem said "unit square" but to avoid fractions I wanted to use a $2\times 2$. The answer is clearly independent of the size of the square, everything scales. Attaching a diagram is a lot of work. Not necessary I think. If you draw a line parallel to a side through a point $P$ in the interior of the square, the two pieces that line is cut into by $P$ can be called $1+x$ and $1-x$, since there are two "general" numbers that add up to $2$. We could have called them $y$ and $2-y$, but that is less elegant.

Comment: Why can't there be decimals? Is 1 plus x equal to 2? So x could either 1 or -1?

Comment: The number $x$ could be any **real** number with $0\le x\lt 1$. So $x$ could be $\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: André, one last question, how did you reach the solution? What was your mindset?

Comment: I *wrote it up* in the chosen style for reasons of elegance. On visualizing a few points, it seemed clear we could always get a triangle by discarding the littlest stick.

Comment: Good picture! You kind of built part of my solution into the labelling.

Answer (score 1):

Though it seems correct to have the probability as 1, it is not one because of the fact that there is more than one rule for a triangle. For example, you can have $A + B > C$ and then have $ A>B+C$ So you will need to consider all three of these cases. In order to answer the question, you can view the heights as $x, 1-x, y, 1-y$ and then we will pick 3 of the altitudes. Without loss of generality, let us pick the points $y, 1-y,$ and $x$. We know that $y+1-y> x$ for all x (except exactly one, but we can view this probability as infinitely small.) Then we have $2y+x>1$ and $1+x >2y$ we can graph these two inequalities and then get the area of the intersection of their graphs, this would be the probability. This is because we did not define y and x, so there is no loss of generality. So the probability after graphing this is $1/2$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}<y<x<1$ satisfies your conditions. Reflections and rotations of this region cover the square.

Answer (score 0):

Let the sides of the square in order be $a,b,c,d$, let the random interior point be $P$ and let the respective altitudes be $t_a$, $t_b$, $t_c$, $t_d$.  Without loss of generality suppose $t_a \leq t_b,t_c,t_d$.

Then we have $t_b=1-t_d\leq 1-t_a=t_c$.

So $t_b\leq t_c$ and similarly $t_d\leq t_c$

Also, since $P$ is an *interior* point, $t_c<1$ and so $t_c<t_b+t_d=1$.

Therefore the altitudes $t_b,t_c,t_d$ can be arranged to form a triangle, so the probability is 1.